# Import package by name of the folder

Tags: python, package

I am trying to make a package from a code that I made. Let's say that 'mypackage' folder contains the `package.py` and the `__init__.py` files. When I want to import this package I have to write

```
import mypackage.package
```

so I can access the functions inside the package.py file. I wonder if it is possible to write only

```
import mypackage
```

or

```
import package
```

to access the functions. Somehow numpy works this way, because one can import numpy via

```
import numpy
```

and numpy is actually the name of the folder: ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy

How can I make a package which is similar to numpy in this sense (in terms of importing)?

Comment: What are the contents of `__init__.py`, if any?

Comment: It has no content.

Comment: You might read numpy's `__init__.py` file, which is in folder you mentioned to get some idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `__init__.py` for this:

```
# mypackage/__init__.py:

from mypackage.package import *
```

This way, when importing `mypackage` you will implicitly import `package`. For example, assume that there is a function `do_something` defined in `mypackage/package.py`. Then, for a file `test.py` defined in the project root you can do the following:

```
# test.py, defined in project root

import mypackage

mypackage.do_something()
```

(Please note that wildcard imports should be avoided, i.e., it is better to only import the functions you need, for instance `from mypackage.package import do_something`).

Comment: And then how I can access a function named 'trial'?

Comment: `import mypackage; x = mypackage.trial()`